# Is there a way to suppress VueJS "Cannot find element" warning

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a script file that contains two Vue apps, that I use across multiple django templates. Apps are `vue1`, and `vue2`, with `el: #vue1-app`, and `el: #vue2-app`.

On one particular page I only use one of those apps, not both. So my html contains only `<div id="vue1-app"></div>` and not both divs with `vue1-app` and `vue2-app` ids. Therefore `Vue` logs warnings `"Cannot find element: #vue2-app"`.

Is there a way to suppress those warning or any other bypass?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Django developer, but I think maybe you can just split out them into two files or add a condition like:

```
const vueApp = document.querySelector('#vue-app')
if(vueApp){
  // mount the app
}
```

Comment: I thought of that, but the app still has some functionality that I use. On created it changes some data variables in vue1.

Answer (score 0):

Vue warnings are not emitted in the production (minified) version of Vue, so you could load `vue.min.js`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#does_not_exist',
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```